# Android game special requirements

Tags: java, android

I'm making a game for android (inspired by brickbreaker), and am just finishing it up. 
Thinking about special android requirements for the game, such as how to handle the various screen sizes, or not needing a back button.

What are other things i should be thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also considered:

- Screen rotation
- When the process goes into the background
- Checking for memory leaks
- Distribution (perhaps in a later stage of development)
- Operating system specifics

Good luck with your project!